# Plot and "Error opening the file. This file is already open or in use by another application."

Tags: r

When I create and save chart as pdf (or png), the file is created correctly, but then I can't open it because windows says:

> Error opening the file. This file is already open or in use by another
>   application.

So I have to close and reopen R so that I can display or delete the file.
Its very frustrating, how can I fix?

Usually I use this code:

```
library(igraph)

g <- barabasi.game(10)

pdf(file = "./output/myImage.pdf")
plot(g)
dev.off()

png(filename = "./output/myImage.png")
plot(g)
dev.off()
```

I use Windows 7

Comment: `dev.off()` should close the file. Does `pdf(file = tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".pdf"));plot(g);dev.off();shell.exec(tf)` work?

Comment: @lukeA Yes it works..

Comment: Ah now I see. `myImage.pdf` is opened in your pdf viewer while you use `pdf()`. That of course does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't overwrite files like `myImage.pdf` while they are opened by another application, like your pdf viewer. I suggest creating temporary files, which goes easy:

```
pdf(file = tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".pdf"))
plot(g)
dev.off()
shell.exec(tf)
```